# Maven concurrent builds on CI server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have an interesting case, in my opinion.  We are using maven, and being that we have to support multiple versions of our product we sometimes have a 1.x and 2.x build structure going on.  When both 1.x and 2.x are built in parallel, sometimes we see

Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata

From what I can tell, the maven-metadata-local.xml in the local user's repo (for the artifact, not the version of the artifact) is being written to at the same time by another maven process.  Is there a way to allow maven to build both of these in parallel, but wait for a write lock on the file to update it?

Comment: This issue is filed as [MINSTALL-54](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINSTALL-54), open since 2008.

Comment: If you are disturbed by this issue just create a patch it's an open source project....

Comment: At which point, they will ignore the patch... cause they are maven maintainers.  There was already a patch supplied years and years ago, which they ignored.  Use the concurrent safe access plugin, below.  No idea why that code isn't part of core maven.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds that you are using the same local repository for all your build jobs which will not work as you already know. The point in Jenkins/Hudson/CI is to use a local maven repository for every build job. You need to configure in Jenkins using a local maven repository to avoid such situations.

You could also install the [Concurrent Safe Local Repository Access](http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html) maven plugins which will allow you to use the same local repository. (Useful if you are dynamically provisioning the agents)

Comment: Using a local repository only works if you're dealing with CI.  If I'm a developer I may need to build both locally at roughly the same time.  Maven should properly handle this.  I'll reply to the note @Joe gave.

Comment: If you really need to build two projects at the same time you can use `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/alternate/repo/location ...`. I know that it does not work in Maven, but never had the requirement to build two projects at the same time on my local machine.

Comment: If you like to use simoultanous access to a local repository just use [Concurrent Safe Local Repository access](http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use the 2nd or 3rd option under Maven settings (Admin/Configure): 
[image]

These options come from the: [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin)

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to access repository concurrently starting from [maven 3.8.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2802)

Require manual libraries installation & config [for concurrent-safe access](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/website/components/resolver-archives/resolver-1.6.3/maven-resolver-synccontext-redisson/index.html)

Here a snippet to setup maven 3.8 in `/opt/mvn` with concurrent-safe repo access (local redis installation required). It can be used in Dockerfile `RUN` or directly:

```
cd /opt \
  && wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.zip \
  && unzip apache-maven-*.zip && rm apache-maven-*.zip \
  && ln -s /opt/apache-maven-* /opt/mvn \
  && wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/valodzka/85bc9fa1af8b6f8c876e99267d22933f/raw/4d18ae882cd624382d508c0217682a874a0744b2/redisson-sync-context-urls.txt \
  && wget --directory-prefix=/opt/mvn/lib/ext/redisson --input-file=redisson-sync-context-urls.txt \
  && sed --in-place '/logging/a load ${maven.home}/lib/ext/redisson/*.jar' /opt/mvn/bin/m2.conf \
  && rm redisson-sync-context-urls.txt
```